# R: Interactive prompt for importing one of multiple locally-sourced datasets?

Tags: r, excel, import, interactive

Using R version 3.1.1 and RStudio Version 0.99.442

I'm creating an interactive script that prompts the user to manually select (type) one of five sites, and then imports an excel spreadsheet of data that corresponds to that site.

I, in essence, took the example script from the readline() help file and adjusted it for my purposes.

The function doesn't throw any errors, and will print cat() lines that I add in, but will not import any of the datasets. I'm sure there's an easy fix to this, but for some reason cannot figure it out. Where am I going wrong in my code?

```
rm(list=ls())
setwd("c:/Users/win7/Dropbox/Data")
library("xlsx")

fun <- function() {
  ANSWER = readline("Which site would you like to analyze? \n
    Enter (type) one of the following: site1, site2, site3: ")
  if (ANSWER == "site1")
    {cat("Okay, loading the site1 data...\n");
      trees = read.xlsx("site1_data.xlsx", sheetName="Trees", header=T);
      cwd = read.xlsx("site1_data.xlsx", sheetName="CWD", header=T)} else
  if (ANSWER == "site2")
    {cat("Okay, loading the site2 data...\n");
      trees = read.xlsx("site2.xlsx", sheetName="Trees", header=T);
      cwd = read.xlsx("site2.xlsx", sheetName="CWD", header=T)} else
  if (ANSWER == "site3")
    {cat("Okay, loading the site3 data...\n");
      trees = read.xlsx("site3.xlsx", sheetName="Trees", header=T);
      cwd = read.xlsx("site3.xlsx", sheetName="CWD", header=T)}
  }

if(interactive()) fun()
```

Apologies if this is a duplicate question - I feel that it should have been answered on SO however could not find an answer in my searches over the last hour.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own issue by writing the data tables to the global environment with "<<-" as opposed to "=". The "trees" object seemed to be locked with some binding, so I avoided this by just writing to "all.trees," and then changing the "all.trees" data to "trees" later.

Working code is here:

```
rm(list=ls())
setwd("c:/Users/win7/Dropbox/Data")
library("xlsx")

fun <- function() {
  ANSWER = readline("Which site would you like to analyze? \n
    Enter (type) one of the following: site1, site2, site3: ")
  if (ANSWER == "site1")
    {cat("Okay, loading the site1 data...\n");
      all.trees <<- read.xlsx("site1_data.xlsx", sheetName="Trees", header=T);
      cwd <<- read.xlsx("site1_data.xlsx", sheetName="CWD", header=T)} else
  if (ANSWER == "site2")
    {cat("Okay, loading the site2 data...\n");
      all.trees <<- read.xlsx("site2.xlsx", sheetName="Trees", header=T);
      cwd <<- read.xlsx("site2.xlsx", sheetName="CWD", header=T)} else
  if (ANSWER == "site3")
    {cat("Okay, loading the site3 data...\n");
      all.trees <<- read.xlsx("site3.xlsx", sheetName="Trees", header=T);
      cwd <<- read.xlsx("site3.xlsx", sheetName="CWD", header=T)}
  }

if(interactive()) fun()

trees = all.trees; rm(all.trees)
```

It works for now, but I'm curious as to why this happened. Can someone explain the different bindings/environments that were preventing my initial attempts?